# Passing Multiselect Listbox Values to a Query with Replace() doesn't Update Results on the Form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a continuous form with a multiselect listbox, called StatusListBox, and I pass all the selected values from the box to an SQL query ("FilterQuery") with a Replace function, changing the SQL code of the query. This works well and updates the text of the query and I can see the changes when I open it, but my continuous form doesn't get updated. I suspect the problem is that I change the text of the query's SQL code after the form has already loaded and not with proper parameters (i.e. `Forms!FormName!Control`)

I use `Me.Requery` to update the form, which works great with textfields which are parameters in the `FilterQuery` SQL code, but not in this case.
I'm new to Access and I'm very puzzled.
Here's the sub:

first I make a string with all the values from the textbox

```
StatusListValues = ""
For Each StatusItem In StatusLIst.ItemsSelected
StatusListValues = StatusListValues & "'" & StatusLIst.ItemData(StatusItem) & "'" & ","
Next StatusItem
StatusListValues = Left(StatusListValues, Len(StatusListValues) - 1)
Debug.Print StatusListValues
```

then I save the current SQL code as a string, replace the previous string of selected values  with current string, then make current string the
"previous" one

```
SQLstring = CurrentDb().QueryDefs("FilterQuery").SQL
SQLstring = Replace(SQLstring, StatusListValuesPrevious, StatusListValues)
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("FilterQuery").SQL = SQLstring
StatusListValuesPrevious = StatusListValues
```

Comment: Why use QueryDefs? I have never used it to filter a form. I also don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I build filter criteria and apply to form Filter property. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: If memory serves, a form has its own copy of its RecordSource which in this case is FilterQuery.  You haven't changed the forms copy of FilterQuery.  So right before me.Requery add me.RecourdSource= "FilterQuery".  you shouldn't need me.Requery at that point but leave it in until you are sure.  Also, as you are doing string building anyway there doesn't seem to be a reason to use FilterQuery.  Just set the recordsource to a string containing the sql query directly.  Here is a youtube example which I have some issues with, but it may be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAcdBiawyzk

Comment: @mazoula Thank you, I didn't know and failed to find in documentation the detail about a copy of query being created.  You approach worked and made sense to me but it appears Kostas K has a better approach than mine, so I rewrote the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid editing the SQL string of an existing query. Instead, you should filter the form based on the selected items.

Create a helper function that returns the selected statuses (if any) if the form of `'a','b','c'` etc.

```
Private Function SelectedStatus() As String
    Dim StatusListValues As String

    For Each StatusItem In StatusLIst.ItemsSelected
        StatusListValues = StatusListValues & "'" & StatusLIst.ItemData(StatusItem) & "'" & ","
    Next StatusItem

    SelectedStatus= Left(StatusListValues, Len(StatusListValues) - 1)

End Function
```

Then, on the `AfterUpdate()` event of the ListBox, get the selected items (if any) and either filter the form, or clear the filter if nothing has been selected.

```
Private Sub YourListBoxControl_AfterUpdate()

    Dim statuses As String
    statuses = SelectedStatus()

    'if no selection, clear the filter
    If statuses = vbNullString Then
        FilterOn = False
        Filter = vbNullString
        Exit Sub
    End if

    'selection made - apply filter
    Filter = "[Status] In (" & statuses & ")"
    FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and is much easier than my approach. Is there any particular reason why modifying original query is bad ?
It seems more straightforward to modify it (or make it parametrized at least) than to apply additional query on top. I understand if this is too broad a question, of course.

Comment: Simply because stored queries have a precompiled query plan. Not a huge difference, but also depends on the complexity of the query.

Comment: chiming in, you are supposed to use parametized queries when the query is complex and used in multiple places.  In Access, Parametized queries are more point and clicky to develop as well. But, I would set up the parametized query so that I could just change the parameters rather than rewrite it, because in theory changing the query adds the overhead of re-optimizing it.  In practice I'm suspicious that the query would not be optimized immediately if it was changed with vba and in that case we loose the benefits of optimization.

Comment: When a parameter is a single value, yes sure, but there's no parameter type that supports a coma delimited array to be used `IN (...)`.